# C++ Makefile Error (openGl)

Tags: c++, c++11, compiler-errors, makefile

My program has 5 files:
main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp a.hpp b.hpp
I was given a skeleton makefile to work with, but Im not that confident when it comes to manipulating it.
When I try running "make" I get this error:

```
#error This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. 
This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the 
-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

I am not sure how to change this Makefile that I have so that my program compiles. This is for a graphic's course, so one of my headers in these files is .

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -Wall
LDFLAGS=
SOURCES=main.cpp a.cpp b.cpp
OBJECTS=$(SOURCES:.cpp=.o)
EXECUTABLE=test
INCLUDE=a.hpp b.hpp
LIBS =  -L /usr/X11R6/lib/ -lglut -lGL -lGLU -lX11 -lXmu -lXi -lm
all: $(SOURCES) $(EXECUTABLE)

$(EXECUTABLE): $(OBJECTS)
        $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) $(OBJECTS) -o $@ $(LIBS)

.cpp.o:
        $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $< -o $(INCLUDE) $@
```

Comment: Isn't error  message crystal clear?

Comment: What part of it is unclear?

Answer (score 0):

You need to supply the hint you got from the error message to the compiler. From the error message;

```
This file requires compiler and library support for the ISO C++ 2011 standard. 
This support is currently experimental, and must be enabled with the 
-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options.
```

To be able to compile, you would need to add `-std=c++11` to your Makefile's compiler flag, like so;

```
CFLAGS = -c -Wall -std=c++11
```

Hope that helps.